# Laravel 5.2 authorize using user model's can method

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem when using user model's can and cannot method. I have a post model and an user model. And I define an add method in `PostPolicy` class:

```
public function add(User $user){
    if($user->isGuest()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

I know when use can or cannot method, the policy class which will be used will be resolved automatically by model instance we pass to can or cannot method, like `$user->can('update',$post)`. But in this example. the `add` method does not need a post instance, So I can't do like this `$user->can('add',$post)`. Can someone tell me how to get done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question.

The funny thing is this isn't documented for Laravel 5.2 but it is for 5.4. So you will have to check if this works for you in Laravel 5.2.

When you don't have an object model to pass into the policy check the documentation says you should pass this instead `Model::class`. In your case, it'd be `Post::class` as the parameter. So it'd be:

```
$user->can('update', Post::class);
```

If this does not work for you in Laravel 5.2 you can always write a Gate instead of a policy and just use the `Gate::allows()` or `Gate::denies` methods:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#gates

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I use policy helper to do this.